Should a diode be placed between the output of voltage regulator and the battery?
When applying constant voltage to a 8-volt lead acid battery using a 7809 voltage regulator,

should a diode be placed after the output pin and before the battery, anode to the output pin and cathode to the battery?
If yes, why?


Are you considering battery health, or 7809 health, or the health of the constant voltage supply? It might help us if you more-fully specify the constant-voltage supply.

What is the capacity of the battery?

@glen_geek I am considering 7809 health. 7809 regulator applies constant voltage to the battery.

@vu2nan For now, the capacity of the battery is 1000 mAh (but finally I will add another 500 mAh).

It does not matter.
You can't charge a lead acid battery directly with a voltage regulator anyway, so you should not be connecting the 7809 output to the battery to begin with, through a diode or directly.
Why? Assume the battery is empty, it could have maybe 7.5V at the terminals. If you connect it to a say 7809 output which has been dropped by a diode to 8.3V, the regulator can't keep it's output at 9V as the battery can sink multiple amps of current and the regulator can't provide enough current.
The 7809 is a voltage regulator, not a battery charger. It needs external circuitry to use a 7809 to make a battery charger.

It might be required depending on the charger type, but not in your application. The diode prevents backfeeding the charger and placing a parasitic load on the battery. The 7809 essentially has the Blocking Diode built-in as a BJT on the output.

Although -- I'd check that on any chip I were buying, by scrutinizing the data sheet, then measuring the discharge current from the battery with the source unplugged.  There's so many different versions of the "plain old" 78xx regulators these days that you can't safely assume they all work the same in peripheral details like that.


should a diode be placed after the output pin and before the battery, anode to the output pin and cathode to the battery?

It is not needed. An 8 V lead acid battery can be take a 9.2 V floating charge, so 1) there is no need to try to drop some of the voltage through a diode, and 2) Although there is a scenario where a diode can serve to protect a 7809, there is (usually) a better alternative location for the diode. If the input pin to the 7809 should become shorted to ground, the 7809 could become damaged. A diode could help protect the 7809 from that scenario. However, if you want to protect from such a risk, a better alternative would be to place the diode between the input pin of the 7809 and the power supply. (However, keep the decoupling capacitor connected directly to the input pin of the 7809.)
It is possible to charge an 8 V lead acid battery with a 7809. But, the 7809 has thermal shutdown. If the battery tries to draw too much current, the 7809 will heat up, and the current supplied to the battery will be quite low. But it will charge, eventually. A battery charging IC would be a better design. Nevertheless, if you have a battery that needs charging and a 7809, and you are not in a hurry, it will work.
Another point to consider is that the 7809 might lose it's voltage regulation if the current drawn falls below 5 mA. The battery may or may not draw that with a float charge. If the battery is to be left un-monitored for a very long time while charging, you may want to place a 1.5 k\$\Omega\$ resistor between the output pin of the 7809 and ground, to ensure there is a minimum current above 5 mA.


When charging voltage is less than the battery voltage and therefore backflow happens, does that "harm" the 78xx regulator or not?

The datasheet for the Texas Instruments LM7805/7812/7815 states (p13)

8.1.1 Shorting the Regulator Input When using large capacitors at the output of these regulators, a protection diode connected input to output (Figure 15) may be required if the input is shorted to ground. Without the protection diode, an input short causes the input to rapidly approach ground potential, while the output remains near the initial VOUT because of the stored charge in the large output capacitor. The capacitor will then discharge through a large internal input to output diode and parasitic transistors. If the energy released by the capacitor is large enough, this diode, low current metal, and the regulator are destroyed. The fast diode in Figure 15 shunts most of the capacitors discharge current around the regulator. Generally no protection diode is required for values of output capacitance ≤ 10 μF.
8.1.2 Raising the Output Voltage Above the Input Voltage Because the output of the device does not sink current, forcing the output high can cause damage to internal low current paths in a manner similar to that just described in Shorting the Regulator Input.

Various brands of the 78xx voltage regulator family may have different characteristics. So, you may find a 78xx that is NOT damaged by backflow. However, unless you have found such a device, and know that your circuit will never substitute for that device one in which backflow can be damaging, you should design your circuit to prevent such backflow.

You said "It is not needed. An 8 V lead acid battery can be take a 9.2 V floating charge, so 1) there is no need to try to drop some of the voltage through a diode". My question is: Is not a diode necessary for preventing current from flowing back from battery to the regulator?

@SA there is no need to protect backflow unless the charging voltage is less than the battery voltage. In that case, the diode would be better placed between the power supply and the 78xx input pin.

When charging voltage is less than the battery voltage and therefore backflow happens, does that "harm" the 78xx regulator or not?

The diode may be required to prevent reverse current flow from the battery, when the charger is switched off.

